# Debugging 32 bit NACL exe on MAC?

Tags: gdb, google-nativeclient

I am wishing to debug 32 bit nacl exe on mac platform. I couldnt debug it out since on mac platform i couldnt find a 32bit nacl-gdb. Has anyone successfully done it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDB for Native Client was released in Pepper 23, so first check that you're using the Pepper 23 version of the NaCl SDK or newer. (To download any new versions of the SDK, issue `./naclsdk update` from your `nacl_sdk` directory. When it's done, you should see a `pepper_23` directory (or newer). Use the tools in that directory.)

In the SDK the GDB binaries are in these locations (example based on Pepper 23):

```
nacl_sdk/pepper_23/toolchain/mac_x86_glibc/bin/i686-nacl-gdb
nacl_sdk/pepper_23/toolchain/mac_x86_glibc/bin/x86_64-nacl-gdb
nacl_sdk/pepper_23/toolchain/mac_x86_newlib/bin/i686-nacl-gdb
nacl_sdk/pepper_23/toolchain/mac_x86_newlib/bin/x86_64-nacl-gdb
```

The two `i686-nacl-gdb` are in fact just symbolic links to the two `x86_64-nacl-gdb`. The `x86_64-nacl-gdb` binaries will allow you to debug both 32-bit and 64-bit x86 NaCl targets. On the Mac, though, Chrome is always 32-bit and will always run the 32-bit `.nexe`, even if your OS or machine is 64-bit.

Both the newlib and the glibc toolchain contains a complete set of tools; this is why you have two `x86_64-nacl-gdb` binaries. Currently, these two do not differ, but for your own sanity it's probably easiest to use the GDB in the same directory as the tools used for your build.

There is some additional guidance at https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/debugging#gdb. The all-important thing is to pass the flag `--enable-nacl-debug` to Chrome or activate it under about:flags in Chrome. This will cause Chrome to wait for the debugger to connect before executing Native Client content.

Comment: Hi Christian, Thanks for quick reply.
I have followed those steps earlier but i am running into some issues. I am using
1)chrome version 25.0.1364.5 dev. 2)NACL pepper_24 3)Newlib tool chain 4)created nacl and pnacl debug exes.
Problem is
1) I couldn't find the Native Client Integrated Runtime (irt) file anywhere on my machine.
2) I just started debugging by mentioning "target remote localhost:4014", this gave a weird output like
Remote debugging using localhost:4014
0x0fc00200 in ?? ()
3) if i press <gdb> next then it says "Cannot find bounds of current function"
Whats wrong in here?

Comment: The program is probably somewhere inside the IRT (integrated runtime of NaCl). You should still be able to set breakpoints in your own code, get stack traces, etc. The IRT comes with Chrome, so look in /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/25.0.1364.4/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Internet Plug-Ins/nacl_irt_x86_32.nexe. Make the debugger aware of the IRT with the command `nacl-irt`. See step 6 in the debugging guide linked above.

Comment: Thank you so much ... it was very much helpful. Merry christmas :-)